# Entity Framework Using a Where Clause on a Nested Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to filter child objects on the retrieval using the following

```
var loanExtractExample = be.LoanCategoryMonitors
                .Where(lcm => lcm.LoanNumber == 5000435)
                .Include(l => l.Loan)
                .Include(le => le.LoanExtracts)
                .Select(le => le.LoanExtracts.Borrowers.Where(b => b.BorrowerNum == 1))
                .ToList();
```

but when I check the entity collection there are 2 borrowers. One with BorrowerNum 1 and one with BorrowerNum = 3.

What am I missing to be able to reduce the borrowers to the correct one?

Comment: I think instead of ToList() you want SingleOrDefault()? Maybe not, if you plan to have more than one with `BorrowerNum = 1`.

Comment: @JamesWhyte still showing 2 Borrower Entities. No there should only be 1 borrower on a loan where BorrowerNum = 1

Comment: You could chop up the Linq statement a little and work backwards from there. I'm in the process of tinkering with a method to get it working but have no test data, so it might not be terribly replicable

Comment: Perhaps you need SingleOrDefault/ToList inside your `.Select(le => ...` statement, after the `Where(b=>b.BorrowerNum == 1)`.

Comment: No luck there either

Comment: Check the actual SQL query using something like SQL Profiler it will help you to understand the problem with this query

Comment: A relatively easy way to check the sql query is using the log function: `be.Database.Log = x => Console.WriteLine(x);` or any other logging target instead of Console.

Comment: By the way... what do you mean by *"when I check the entity collection"* it doesn't sound as if you check the result of your query but more as if you check the (cached?) contents of your context...

Comment: @grek40 No When I examine loanExtractExample after execution I see 2 borrowers. The SQL looked correct here is the last where clause
        
  WHERE ([Extent1].[LoanNumber] = [Extent4].[FolderID]) AND (3 = [Extent3].[BorrowerNum])

Extent3 is the Borrower Table and Extent1 is the LoanCategoryMonitor table

Comment: @Tim __`3 = [Extent3].[BorrowerNum]`__ looks *everything but correct* since you expect `BorrowerNum == 1` in your question. Please be far more specific with every aspect of your problem if you expect help (precise description of expected and actual output, full SQL when asked, ...)

Comment: Sorry I forget to edit that. I was doing some additional testing. I found the data type of BorrowerNum was a short. I failed to return that to 1 on the last test. There should only be 1 row with BorrowerNum = 1 or 1 row with BorrowerNum = 3 so in any case I should only have one borrower returned.

Comment: Ok, I feel like an Idiot now. So it was working but not as I had expected. I had expected that when navigating to the borrowers I would have only retrieved 1 that matched the request. However, the variable loanExtractExample was showing the Borrower with the correct BorrowerNum at the root of the entity. So this was not exactly the behavior I was expecting. I still needed LoanCategorieMonitors at the root. So I can just filter like so when I need the borrower var borrowerOne = loanExtractExample.LoanExtracts.Borrowers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BorrowerNum == 1);

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Select for the borrowers I believe would returning the borrowers for loan category monitors where a monitor had a borrower with ID 1. I believe what you are looking for is:

```
var matchingBorrowers = be.LoanCategoryMonitors
                .Where(lcm => lcm.LoanNumber == 5000435)
                .SelectMany(le => le.LoanExtracts.Borrowers) // Borrowers for loan extracts against loan 5000435...
                .Where(b => b.BorrowerNum == 1)) // Of those borrowers, those with BorrowerNum = 1.
                .ToList();
```

Includes aren't needed since you're not retrieving a loan category monitor, but you might want to add any .Include() statements for child references of the borrowers that are returned. (after the `.SelectMany()`)